# What is the best way to handle timed callbacks that affect an object shared across different threads?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have a class, let's call it Foo foo, which holds data that is useful to multiple threads. These threads may call read and write operations (e.g. foo->emplace(something)) which I protected by a mutex inside Foo and added mutex locks to the operations. Here's where I'm uncertain when it comes to implementation. I have to add another piece of shared information to foo where I have to call foo->emplace2(somethingElse) and this will store somethingElse in a std::set but this should only be stored for a minute.

What is the right approach to this? Do I create a new thread from inside foo whenever emplace2 is called and inside this thread emplace, sleep for 60 seconds, then erase? I feel like there is a better way than creating lots of threads every time emplace2 is called.

Not looking for code, just general implementation advice.

Comment: why do you remove it from the set after 60 seconds? Don't do that. Instead store the element together with a timestamp. Once it is expired you know that it cannot be used anymore and be overwritten when adding other elements to the set. Btw imho the question is too vague. Can you show some code and make the question more specific?

Comment: @idclev463035818 the set is supposed to keep a record of temporarily blacklisted sources and once their 60 second ban is over then they should be removed from the blacklisted sources list and regain some functionality. I'm not allowed to post the code unfortunately as it's industry code and I don't have permission to show it to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options:

## One thread per request

a.k.a your solution

Advantages:

- easy to implement
- precise remove times

Disadvantages:

- lots of threads created. But then again all the threads sleep for their whole life so it might not be a problem worth solving.

## One queue and one thread that periodically checks expired requests

Create a queue that stores all the requests along with their expire time. Have one thread that periodically wakes up and deletes all expired threads

Advantages:

- easy-ish to implement
- just one thread

Disadvantages:

- A compromise must be made:

  - increase the wake-up and check frequency: this increases the precision time of removing requests, but also increases the number of useless wake-ups
  - lower the wake-up and check frequency: this lowers the precision time of removing requests but decreases the number of useless wake-ups

## One thread with precise wake-ups

Create one queue with all the requests along with their expire time. Have one thread that wakes up only when the next request expires.

When a request is added: signal and wake the thread, recompute the next expire and sleep until that time.

On wake-up: delete the expiring request,  compute the time until the next expire and sleep until then.

Advantages:

- Best performance
- precise remove times

Disadvantage:

- difficult-ish to implement

---

> What is the best way to ...

As always the answer is: "Is depends". I gave you some options along with a brief analysis of each. It's up to you to decide which to implement and the decision is a balancing act between performance requirements versus implementation and maintenance costs.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the third solution. Works really well!